# Optimize mongo aggregation with match and sort

Tags: mongodb, sorting, filter, aggregation-framework

I've an aggregation pipeline that is getting quite slow. Let's say my documents looks like:

```
{
  value1,
  value2,
}
```

and that they are indexed on both fields.

My pipeline is:

```
collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { value1: someVar },
  },
  {
    $sort: { value2: 1 },
  },
  {
    $limit: 5,
  },
], cb);
```

The issue is that there's quite a few documents matching (~10k) and that I'm losing the index advantage on the second step of the pipeline. Is there a good way to improve that that would leverage the indexing for both match and sort?

Comment: How is your index defined ? Do you've single index each for `value1` and `value 2` ?

Comment: yes: `collection.ensureIndex({ value1: 1, value2: 1 })`

Comment: That index won't support sorting only by value2, it is a compound index, you will use both.

Comment: You're right. My bad. I changed it to `collection.ensureIndex({ value1: 1, value2: 1 }); collection.ensureIndex({ value2: 1 });` Should that work better?

Comment: @Euclides An initial `$match` stage followed by a `$sort` actually **does** want the original compound index. The aggregation query as currently written is equivalent to: `db.collection.find({ value1: someVar }).sort({value2: 1}).limit(5)`.

Comment: @Guig What specific version of MongoDB server are you using? Can you add the output of [`explain:true`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-explain-option) and `db.collection.getIndexes()`? Assuming you have a suitable compound index to match & return the results in sorted order (eg. `{value1: 1, value2: 1}`) your initial `$match` and `$sort` both factor into the index selection and there is no need for an in-memory sort. See: [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/).

Comment: @Stennie you are quite right,  though it is strange.